# Empty microphone data using Crosswalk in Ionic 2 application

Tags: android, getusermedia, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

In my Ionic 2 application, I use the WebAudio API to record audio (based on  https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs). This is working on Chrome and, after putting the right permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

and requesting microphone access through the `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` plugin, on Android version 6.0.1 (Samsung Galaxy S6).

However, it doesn't work on Android 4.2.2 (Samsung Galaxy S4) because it doesn't seem to support `getUserMedia`, so I decided to install the crosswalk plugin:

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`

After that I see `getUserMedia` can be used (through a Modernizr check). However, now the audio recorder returns only silence (on both versions of Android). I have checked that the permissions are still set correctly. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In the end, it seemed to be due to the (stable) version of crosswalk I was using; I fixed it by using the beta release:

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview --variable XWALK_VERSION="org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:21.51.546.7"`

Also see: https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7030

Comment: This fixed the issue, in combination with the RECORD_AUDIO and MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permissions. Btw, don't forget to request the permissions using the permissions plugin: https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions